# new to javascript, trying to understand function returning a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand what is going on here:

```
if (!Object.create) {
Object.create = (function () {
    var F = function(){};

    return function (o) {
        if (arguments.length !== 1) {
            throw new Error('Object.create implementation only accepts one parameter.');
        }
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}());
```

}

what does F.prototype mean... How does returning a function work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: *"what does F.prototype mean... How does returning a function work"* Those are two very different questions. Which are you asking about?

Comment: welcome to functional programming !!! for learning see this link - http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

Comment: Check here http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Answer (score 3):

These are two separate questions. The concept of a prototype and what it means is separate from the concept of returning functions. I will do my best to try and explain.

**What does F.prototype mean?**

Javascript does not support inheritance in the classical sense, but rather uses prototype inheritance to pass object properties from one function to another.

All Javascript objects contain a prototype field by default. The prototype field is always initially set to the base Object object. (You can create a new instance of Object by doing 
`var x = new Object()` or by doing `var x = {}`.) You can create objects that set the prototype to another object thereby gaining access to their methods and properties that are placed on the prototype.

Let's walk through an example to illustrate.

Consider you create a constructor to create a Bird object.

```
function Bird(name) { 
   var me = this; 
   this.name = name; 
   this.flying = false; 
   this.fly = function() { me.flying = true; }; 
}

Bird.prototype.fly = function() { this.flying = true; }

Bird.prototype.land = function() { this.flying = false; }
```

If we look at the details of this object (which you can do using console.dir(obj), or by using Chrome developer tools):

[image: Details of Bird Constructor]

Now consider you want to create another bird object that implements the Object Bird. You would do something like this.

```
function Duck(name) {
   this.name = name;
   this.quack = function() {
      console.log("quack");
   }
}
```

If you look at the details of this object you see:

[image: Duck Construcotor]

Now if you want to make the duck fly, you do not have a method on it yet. You need to set the prototype of Duck to be Bird. You do that by doing something like this:

```
function Duck(name) {
   this.name = name;
   this.quack = function() {
     console.log("quack");
   }
}

Duck.prototype = new Bird();
```

Now when you look at the details of the object you will see that the prototype is now set to bird.

[image: Duck Constructor 2]

In short prototypes are used to provide code reuse among objects. Programmers coming from object oriented backgrounds can use prototypes to provide the same mechanisms as inheritance. Mozilla has a good [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) that goes into more depth.

**How does returning a function work?**

Javascript is a functional programming language. One of the principles of the functional programming paradigm is the existence function as first class objects. Among other things this means that functions are treated the same as any other object.

A function returning a function means nothing different then a function that returns a string.

```
 function getString() {
      return "I am a string";
    }
```

You can use the result of this function in whatever way you choose. A function that returns a function is the same way.

```
function getFunctionToGetSomethingImportant() {
  return function() {
    return "I am something important";
  }
}
```

Now when you want to get a function that returns a function that does something important you can do this:

```
var x = getFunctionToGetSomethingImportant();
x();
```

Despite these use cases having little value, using functions as first class objects is incredibly valuable. Functions can be treated like other objects which means they can be passed into other functions as parameters (a concept called higher order functions).

```
function filter(list, function(element) {
      return element < 0;
   });
```

The function filter takes as its second parameter a function that takes an element parameter. An implementation of filter would loop through each element in list and apply the function given as the second paramater. This is one example of many important use cases of functions as first class objects. This [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) article contains more information.

Comment: `this.prototype = new Bird(name);` is wrong. It should be `Duck.prototype` and should be placed outside of the constructor. You are not really setting the prototype here. You are just creating a property called `prototype` on the created object.

Answer (score 0):

Initialy F is empty function and new F() returns empty object, i.e {}

after

```
F.prototype = o
```

F as class gets properties of the object o

for example if o={a:1}, then new F() returns {a:1}

this is the same like you define F as

```
F = function(){
  this.a = 1;
}
```

but in your example you can create new object based on the class of object o passed to the create() function

Comment: Defining a property in the prototype of a function is NOT the same as defining it inside the function, with `this`.

Comment: right, not exactly the same. this overwrites prototype properties and methods.

Answer (score -6):

```
function dostuff() {
  return function () {console.log('hello')}
}

f = dostuff();
f();

--output:--
hello
```

.

```
Array.prototype.greet = function() {console.log('hello')};

[1, 2, 3].greet();

--output:--
hello
```

.

```
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.speak = function() {console.log('Ruff, ruff!') };
}

mydog = new Dog("Joey")
console.log(mydog.name);
mydog.speak();

--output:--
Joey
Ruff, ruff!
```

.

```
function Dog() {

}

Dog.prototype.speak = function() {console.log("Ruff, ruff!")};

mydog = new Dog();
mydog.speak();

--output:--
Ruff, ruff!
```

.

```
function Dog() {

}

var obj = {
  name: "Joey",
  speak: function() {console.log("Ruff, ruff!")}
}

Dog.prototype = obj;

mydog = new Dog();
console.log(mydog.name);
mydog.speak();

--output:--
Joey
Ruff, ruff!


obj.jump = function() {console.log("Look at me jump!")};
mydog.jump();

--output:--
Look at me jump!
```

.

```
var F = function() {

};

var o = {
  "greet": function() {console.log('hello')} 
};

F.prototype = o;
f = new F();
f.greet();

--output:--
hello
```

Comment: `-1` - This answer really explains nothing, it's just a mess of code that happen to use a few of the language features talked about.